# Data structure in python for 2d range counting queries

Tags: python, spatial-query

I need a data structure for doing 2d range counting queries (i.e. how many points are in a given rectangle).

I think my best bet is range tree (it can count in log^2, or even log after some optimizations). Does it sound like a good choice? Does anybody know about a python implementation or will I have to write one myself?

Answer (score 2):

See [scipy.spatial.KDTree](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/spatial.html) for one implementation.

There's also a less generic (but occasionally more useful, particularly with regards to what you have in mind) implementation using shapelib's quadtree.  See [this blog](http://sgillies.net/blog/275/python-quadtree/) and the corresponding [package in PyPi](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Quadtree/).

There are probably other implementations, too, but those are the two that I've used...

Comment: I didn't use it because I thought kdtree is O(sqrt(n)). I was talking about a different data structure (range tree) which is O(log^2(n)). However, it seems they are using a really cool optimization for multiple queries, and the article (http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~agray/nips-final.ps) mentions exactly what I'm trying to to do as an application for the method (fast kernel density estimation). So I'll give it a try. Thanks!

Comment: @Dani So, are you aware of any current 2D range tree (I am especially interested in the O(log^2(n)) complexity) implementation in Python anywhere nowadays?